# Using Play with Memcached on Heroku without storing hard-coded config details

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, memcached, playframework-1.x

I'd like to configure a Play Framework on Heroku to work with Memcached.

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/kUZpxlSIlbE) suggests I use hard-coded config values. [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache) states the user/password/hosts are exposed as enviornment variables ... is there a way to tell Play to load these directly, without using hard-coded values?

This is what I tried:

```
%prod.memcached=enabled
%prod.memcached.host=%MEMCACHE_SERVERS
%prod.memcached.user=%MEMCACHE_USERNAME
%prod.memcached.password=%MEMCACHE_PASSWORD
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Did you add the memcache add-on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around for you issue.  In Heroku when you configure the "Memcache Add On"
it gives you the following environment variables.

```
${MEMCACHE_PASSWORD}       
${MEMCACHE_SERVERS}   
${MEMCACHE_USERNAME}
```

but when setting the %prod.memcached.host=${MEMCACHE_SERVERS} it also needs the default port in order to operate correctly (i.e. ${MEMCACHE_SERVERS}:11211).

Therefore you can add an extra environment variable by doing the following

1. `heroku config:add MEMCACHE_SERVER=${MEMCACHE_SERVERS}:11211` in your console
2. set `%prod.memcached.host=${MEMCACHE_SERVER}` in your conf file
3. restart your app

---or---

figure out a way to append the port(11211) at the end of `${MEMCACHE_SERVERS}` environment variable in the conf file.  Which I don't know how to do because of the ":" character will throw an exception on startup.

I got the same error in play 2.x, but should work for play 1.x.

Comment: Interesting, I'll go it a try.

Comment: Well, if I recall correctly I was't able to make that work, but I ended up making the username & password from config, but take the server as a hardcoded value from `heroku config` output.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
%prod.memcached.host=${MEMCACHE_SERVERS}
%prod.memcached.user=${MEMCACHE_USERNAME}
%prod.memcached.password=${MEMCACHE_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Is `${}` the standard syntax to access environment variables?

Comment: yeah, I got similar errors to what I got before I had hard coded user/pass in the config file. I'll have to try it again sometime when I get a chance.

Comment: I just used this exact config with Play 1.2.4 and the `memcache` addon and everything worked fine.  Not sure what might be wrong.